# How to connect sqlite3 to my project mfc DLL which is import to c#

Tags: c++, dll, sqlite, mfc

when I am tring to connect sqlite3 to my project mfc DLL which is import to c#. There comes error' one or more multiply defined symbols found' how to solve this.
first I include sqlite3.h and add sqlite3.lib,create a database using sqliteBrowser in my project folder to my project . Where Dcode is my mfc Dll project and project path Dcode.dll F:\project\ Project\Dcode\Dcode\
then write code

```
sqlite3 *conn; //connection object

const char *dbname="F:\\project\\ Project \\db.s3db";//destination for DB

 int s=sqlite3_open(dbname,&conn);//allocating memory to the sqlite3 object using sqlite3_open constructors  

if(s==SQLITE_OK)
{                      
 std::cout<<"Opened database successfully\n";
}
```

then errors
Error   115 error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
Error   112 error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall type_info::type_info(class type_info    const &)" (??0type_info@@AAE@ABV0@@Z) already defined in libcmtd.lib(typinfo.obj)   F:\project\Project \Dcode\Dcode\MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj) Dcode

Error   113 error LNK2005: "private: class type_info & __thiscall type_info::operator=(class type_info const &)" (??4type_info@@AAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) already defined in libcmtd.lib(typinfo.obj)    F:\project\ Project \Dcode\Dcode\MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj)    Dcode
Error   109 error LNK2005: __localtime64_s already defined in libcmtd.lib(loctim64.obj) F:\project\ Project \Dcode\Dcode\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   Dcode
Error   110 error LNK2005: _atoi already defined in libcmtd.lib(atox.obj)   F:\project\ Project \Dcode\Dcode\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   Dcode
Error   107 error LNK2005: _free already defined in libcmtd.lib(dbgfree.obj)    F:\project\ Project\Dcode\Dcode\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)    Dcode
Error   108 error LNK2005: _malloc already defined in libcmtd.lib(dbgmalloc.obj)    F:\project\ Project \Dcode\Dcode\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   Dcode
Error   105 error LNK2005: _memmove already defined in libcmtd.lib(memmove.obj) F:\project\ Project \Dcode\Dcode\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   Dcode
Error   111 error LNK2005: _realloc already defined in libcmtd.lib(dbgrealloc.obj)  F:\project\ Project \Dcode\Dcode\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   Dcode
Error   106 error LNK2005: _strncmp already defined in libcmtd.lib(strncmp.obj) F:\project\ Project \Dcode\Dcode\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)   Dcode

Comment: have you added sqlite3.dll file??

Comment: sqlite3.lib file is added

Comment: where to add sqlite.dll inside project folder or inside source file

Comment: inside project folder, where all .cpp and .h files are placed.

Comment: thats good, enjoy..!!